# Count unique values for every column

Tags: r, dataframe, count, unique

I would like to return the count of the unique (distinct) values for every column in a data frame. For example, if I have the table:

```
 Testdata <- data.frame(var_1 = c("a","a","a"), var_2 = c("b","b","b"), var_3 = c("c","d","e"))

 var_1 | var_2 | var_3
 a     | b     | c 
 a     | b     | d
 a     | b     | e
```

I would like the output to be:

```
 Variable | Unique_Values
 var_1    | 1
 var_2    | 1
 var_3    | 3
```

I have tried playing around with loops using the unique function, e.g.

```
 for(i in names(Testdata)){
    # Code using unique function
 }
```

However I suspect there is a simpler way.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You could use `apply`:

```
apply(Testdata, 2, function(x) length(unique(x)))
# var_1 var_2 var_3 
#     1     1     3
```

Comment: @user2721117, I would suggest `lapply` over `apply` as an approach that scales better. For example `lapply(Testdata, function(x) length(unique(x))`. Some bigger test data: `Testdata <- data.frame(replicate(15, sample(letters[1:sample(26, 1)], 1e6, replace = TRUE)))`

Answer (score 32):

In `dplyr`:

```
Testdata %>% summarise_all(n_distinct)
```

( For those curious about the complete syntax.

In `dplyr >0.8.0` using `purrr` syntax:

```
Testdata %>% summarise_all(list(~n_distinct(.)))
```

In `dplyr <0.8.0`:

```
Testdata %>% summarise_all(funs(n_distinct(.)))
```

)

For more information on summarizing multiple columns found here: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/summarise_all.html

Answer (score 8):

Using the `lengths`function:

```
lengths(lapply(Testdata, unique))

# var_1 var_2 var_3 
#     1     1     3
```

Answer (score 6):

This is actually an improvement on the comment by @Ananda Mahto. It didn't fit in the comment so I decided to add as an answer.

`sapply` is actually marginally faster than `lapply`, and gives the output in a more compact form, just like the output from `apply`.

A test run result on actual data:

```
> start <- Sys.time()
> apply(datafile, 2, function(x)length(unique(x)))
          symbol.           date     volume 
             1371            261      53647 
> Sys.time() - start
Time difference of 1.619567 secs
> 
> start <- Sys.time()
> lapply(datafile, function(x)length(unique(x)))
$symbol.
[1] 1371

$date
[1] 261

$volume
[1] 53647

> Sys.time() - start
Time difference of 0.07129478 secs
> 
> start <- Sys.time()
> sapply(datafile, function(x)length(unique(x)))
          symbol.              date             volume 
             1371               261              53647 
> Sys.time() - start
Time difference of 0.06939292 secs
```

The `datafile` has around 3.5 million rows.

Quoting the help text:

> sapply is a user-friendly version and wrapper of lapply by default
>   returning a vector, matrix or, if simplify = "array", an array if
>   appropriate, by applying simplify2array(). sapply(x, f, simplify =
>   FALSE, USE.NAMES = FALSE) is the same as lapply(x, f).

Answer (score 4):

Here, I've used `dplyr` and `tidyr` to count (using your `Testdata` data frame):

```
Testdata %>% 
  gather(var, value) %>% 
  distinct() %>% 
  count(var)

# # A tibble: 3 × 2
#     var     n
#   <chr> <int>
# 1 var_1     1
# 2 var_2     1
# 3 var_3     3
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative:

```
aggregate(values ~ ind, unique(stack(Testdata)), length)
#     ind values
# 1 var_1      1
# 2 var_2      1
# 3 var_3      3
```

This requires the columns be `character`.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried all solution and two of the above solutions did not work one with aggregate and the tidyr ones but two of them using did not work. I think using a data table is a good choice ,

```
setDT(Testdata)[, lapply(.SD, uniqueN), .SDcols=c("var_1","var_2","var_3")]
   #    var_1 var_2 var_3
   # 1:     1     1     3
```

I tried to compare them from each other

```
library(microbenchmark)
Mycomp = microbenchmark(
  apply = apply(Testdata, 2, function(x)length(unique(x))),
  lapply = lapply(Testdata, function(x)length(unique(x))),
  sapply = sapply(Testdata, function(x)length(unique(x))),
  #base = aggregate(values ~ ind, unique(stack(Testdata)), length),
  datatable = setDT(Testdata)[, lapply(.SD, uniqueN), .SDcols=c("var_1","var_2","var_3")],
  times=50
)

#Unit: microseconds
#      expr     min      lq     mean   median      uq     max neval cld
#     apply 163.315 176.678 192.0435 181.7915 192.047 608.859    50  b 
#    lapply 138.217 147.339 157.9684 153.0640 165.829 254.145    50 a  
#    sapply 160.338 169.124 178.1486 174.3965 185.548 203.419    50  b 
# datatable 667.937 684.650 698.1306 696.0160 703.390 874.073    50   c
```

Answer (score 1):

`collapse::fNdistinct` takes a `data.frame`.

```
library(collapse)
fNdistinct(Testdata)
# var_1 var_2 var_3 
#     1     1     3
```

And it is fast. Data with 10000 rows and 10000 columns:

```
Testdata = data.frame(replicate(1e4, sample(letters[1:sample(26, 1)], 1e4, replace = TRUE)))
system.time(fNdistinct(Testdata))
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.38    0.00    0.37
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(purrr)
Testdata %>% map_dbl(n_distinct)
var_1 var_2 var_3 
    1     1     3 

# in your format
Testdata %>% map_dbl(n_distinct)%>%melt(value.name = "unique_counts")
      unique_counts
var_1             1
var_2             1
var_3             3
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors' question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.

Answer (score 0):

With more recent syntax using `dplyr`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

Testdata <- data.frame(var_1 = c("a","a","a"), var_2 = c("b","b","b"), var_3 = c("c","d","e"))

Testdata %>% 
  summarise(across(everything(), n_distinct)) %>%
  pivot_longer(everything())
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>   name  value
#>   <chr> <int>
#> 1 var_1     1
#> 2 var_2     1
#> 3 var_3     3
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>