# R Shiny column ordinality

Tags: r, csv, shiny, data.table

I have a section of code that allows a CSV file to be uploaded, converted into a data table, and then displayed back into the UI in the main panel. The column/variable names are collected and sent back to the UI sidebar with a checkbox to activate them for other calculations. I want to have three columns in the sidebar, the first is column name pulled dynamically, the second is supposed to be the current number of unique values found in each column, and the third would be the number of categories I want to bin them into.

UI.R

```
fluidRow(
  column(6, checkboxGroupInput("dsnamesGrp","Variable name")),
  column(3, textOutput("output.dsordsGrp")),
  column(3, numericInput("assignBin","Bins", 12))
),
```

Server.R

```
dsnames <- c()
ordinality <- c()

observeEvent(input$datafile, ({
  dsnames <- names(data_set())
  cb_options <- list()
  cb_options[dsnames] <- dsnames
  updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "dsnamesGrp", label = "Variable name", choices = cb_options, selected = "")

  ordinality <- lapply(data_set, function(x)length(unique(x)))
  ord_values <- list()
  ord_values[ordinality] <- renderDataTable(ordinality)
  output$dsordsGrp <- ord_values

  })
)

output$choose_columns <- renderUI({

  if(is.null(input$dataset))
    return()
  colnames <- names(contents)
  checkboxGroupInput("columns", "Choose columns", choices  = colnames, selected = "")
})
```

There are three issues I am having. One, how do I collect the number of unique values for each column and pass them to the UI as a list beside the column names? I thought I could mimic the code for collecting column names that I found on here, but I get:

```
Warning: Error in as.vector: cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'list'
```

The algorithm I'm using to accomplish this I got from [R Count unique values for every column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22196078/r-count-unique-values-for-every-column)

Second, how do I add the column title for the ordinality (Ord) as well as the number of target bins (Bins)?

Last I have not even begun to write the binning section but it will have to do with having a user input box of some sort to get the number of bins. I'm sure its not that difficult but I cannot figure out how to have one box created for each row - that is for each column dynamically.

Update: I realize I put too many items in this one question. The answer helped a lot, I will post the other questions separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class of the object that is being handled in shiny is wrong you need to 'unlist()' a list somewhere... use the below example to find the class of each data object in your script:

in your server

```
output$info <- renderText({
   print(unlist(data_object))
})
```

and in your UI

```
textOuput('info')
```

and debug it from there.