# Count number of unique instances in a column depending on values in other columns

Tags: r, count, distinct, apply

I've got the following table (which is called train) (in reality much bigger)

```
 UNSPSC adaptor alert bact blood collection packet patient ultrasoft whit
 514415       0     0    0     0          0      0       0         1    0
 514415       0     0    0     1          0      0       0         1    0
 514415       0     0    1     0          0      0       0         1    0
 514415       0     0    0     0          0      0       0         1    0
 514415       0     0    0     0          0      0       0         1    0
 514415       0     0    0     0          0      0       0         1    0
 422018       0     0    0     0          0      0       0         1    0
 422018       0     0    0     0          0      0       0         1    0
 422018       0     0    0     1          0      0       0         1    0
 411011       0     0    0     0          0      0       0         1    0
```

I want to calculate the number of unique UNSPSC per column where the value is equal to 1. So for column blood it will be 2 and for column ultrasoft will be 3.

I'm doing this but don't know how to continue:

```
apply(train[,-1], 2, ......)
```

I'm trying to not to use loops.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22196078/r-count-unique-values-for-every-column.

Comment: If you want to get the number of 1 values, an option is  `colSums(rowsum('+'(df1[-1] == 1), df1[,1]) > 0)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To continue from where you left, we can use `apply` with `margin=2` and calculate the `length` of `unique` values of "UNSPSC" for each column.

```
apply(train[-1], 2, function(x) length(unique(train$UNSPSC[x==1])))

#adaptor      alert       bact      blood collection     packet 
#     0          0          1          2          0          0 
#patient  ultrasoft       whit 
#     0          3          0
```

---

Better option is with `sapply`/`lapply` which gives the same result but unlike `apply` does not convert the dataframe into matrix.

```
sapply(train[-1], function(x) length(unique(train$UNSPSC[x==1])))
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have columns of only 0 and 1, like in the example, just use colSums:

colSums(train[,-1]) # you remove the non numeric columns before use, like UNSPSC

```
# adaptor      alert       bact      blood collection     packet    patient 
#         0          0          1          2          0          0          0 
# ultrasoft       whit
#        10          0
```

Comment: You need to count by `UNSPSC`, not to remove it - this is not an correct answer

Comment: For doing the sum of colums you shall remove it, other whise it nonsensical. check it please before disregarding a proper answer with a simple and wrong comment. You can see that my output is exactly the same than the previous one, with a much simpler and concise r expression

Comment: "*So for column blood it will be 2 and for column ultrasoft will be 3.*" - as OP asked for. Your answer is not the same - you have 10 for ultrasoft.