# creating dataframe of stats from another dataframe in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following code.

```
n_manu <- mpg %>% dplyr::select(manufacturer) %>% n_distinct()
n_model <- mpg %>% dplyr::select(model) %>% n_distinct()
n_year <- mpg %>% dplyr::select(year) %>% n_distinct()
```

I want to put this in a dataframe that looks like so:
Is there a way I can do this elegantly without 3 lines of code for calculating the distinct valuse?

```
stat      value
n_manu    15
n_model   38
n_year    2
```

Comment: Also consider checking out this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22196078/count-unique-values-for-every-column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

mpg %>% 
  summarise(across(c(manufacturer, model, year), n_distinct))
```

Gives

```
# A tibble: 1 × 3
  manufacturer model  year
         <int> <int> <int>
1           15    38     2
```

and

```
mpg %>% 
  summarise(across(c(manufacturer, model, year), n_distinct)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to="stat")
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  stat         value
  <chr>        <int>
1 manufacturer    15
2 model           38
3 year             2
```

From there you can finesse "row labels" with ease.

To save the results as a dataframe, simply assign the result of the pipe to an object:

```
summaryStats <- mpg %>% 
  summarise(across(c(manufacturer, model, year), n_distinct)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to="stat")
```

Comment: This is awesome! How do I get the column names to be n_vets, n_clais, n_stn? I would like to do this without explicitly naming each mapping..

Comment: "n_vets, n_clais, n_stn"?  That's not what you asked for in your original question.  The problem is that your transformation from original column name to "stat label" is inconsistent.  To me that means you have either to supply names manually or write a custom transform function.  The closest I can get is `mpg %>% 
  summarise(across(c(manufacturer, model, year), n_distinct)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to="stat") %>% 
  mutate(stat=paste0("n_", str_sub(stat, 1, 5)))`, which gives labels `"n_manuf"`, `"n_model"` and `"n_year"`.

Comment: I see.. also how does this work if i want to add a new stat that's the mean of `displ`? I can't simply add another statement in the summarise fucntion it seems.

Comment: Please read the online help and vignettes for `across`.  You can provide a `list` of functions as the second argument to `across`.  However, since two of your input variables are character rather than numeric, this will add a certain complexity to what you are trying to do.  `mpg %>% 
  summarise(
    across(c(manufacturer, model, year), n_distinct),
    mean_displ=mean(displ)
  )` is also a possibility.